# Numpy.save list of different sized arrays gives: TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, python-unicode, readlines

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

mylist = [np.arange(0,1, 0.5), np.arange(0,2,0.5)]

np.save('mylist', mylist)

with open('mylist.npy') as last:
    print(lst[0])
```

I'm getting the error

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2461c8fce207> in <module>
      6 
      7 with open('mylist.npy') as lst:
--->  8     print(lst[0])

TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

I've tried modifying the code according to other posts that are similar, such as including `lst = lst.read()` or `lst = lst.readlines()`, but that gives me a Unicode error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `np.save(…` Save an array to a **binary file** in NumPy `.npy` format while `open('mylist.npy')` seems to open a **text file** …

Comment: Hmmmm... I've just tried `open('mylist.npy', 'rb')` which is supposed to read it as a binary file, and then `print(mylist.read()[0])` returns 147, which makes no sense to me. And `print(mylist.readlines())` returns `b"\x93NUMPY\x01\x00v\x00{'descr': '|O', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (2,), }\n"`

Comment: Use `np.load`.  You may need to `allow_pickle`.  See the docs.  Read `save` docs while you are at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as commented by hpaulj, is to use `np.load` rather than `read` or `readlines`.

```
import numpy as np

mylist = [np.arange(0,1, 0.5), np.arange(0,2,0.5)]

np.save('mylist', mylist)

with open('mylist.npy') as last:
    lst = np.load(lst, allow_pickle = True)
    print(lst[0])
```